# Evaluating a complex function integration on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate

$$ \int_c \frac {1}{z \sin z} dz$$ where:

$$ C: |z| = 3 $$

I know that z = 0 is a non-removable singularity. It also might be an essential singularity since $sin z$ will cause a singular behavior if I used the Taylor expansion in the denominator. Does the function have to be analytic on the inside of the circle $ C $ to use Cauchy- Goursat theorem? Is there any way to evaluate this integral without using the residue theorem? I am trying to find a quick solution to avoid the use of the residue theorem because it is quite difficult.

Comment: use that $\displaystyle\frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} z^k$ for $|z| < 2\pi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a few summands (*very* few) of the power series around $\;z=0\;$ to see what's going on, and then use the well known development for a geometric series (fill in details):

$$z\sin z=z\left(z-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots\right)=z^2\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\frac1{z\sin z}=\frac1{z^2}\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}6+...}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=\frac1{z^2}+\frac16+\ldots$$

and now use that

$$\oint_\gamma z^ndz=\begin{cases}2\pi i\;,&n=-1\\{}\\0\;,&-1\neq n\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}\;,\;\;\gamma\;\;\text{any simple closed path around zero}$$

Of course, the above only shows the residue is zero, which I can't see why you say it "quite difficult": you can do as shown above, or with the formula (observe zero is a *double* pole):

$$\lim_{z\to0} \left(z^2f(z)\right)'=\lim_{z\to0} \left(\frac z{\sin z}\right)'=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z-z\cos z}{\sin^2z}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\rlap{\;\;/}\sin z}{2\rlap{\;\;/}\sin z\cos z}=0$$

Comment: I think I was intimidated by the residue theorem because $ sin z $ in the denominator causes essential singularity behavior. Meaning that there is more than one residue to be calculated since $sin z = 0 $ whenever $ z = n \pi $ where $ n $ is any integer. I did not know how many residues are inside of the circle C. And I was not sure that the order of the pole at $ z = 0 $ is 1 or 2. Now I see that even if I include all the residues at $z = z_n $, it would not make any difference because all of them are zero.

Comment: @Josh Indeed so. Just remember that an *essential* singularity is one which is *not* a a pole. Also, you can say that developing a Laurent series around it would give an infinite number of negative powers

Comment: One last question. Although the value of the integral turned out to be zero using the residue theorem, it would be wrong to use Cauchy-Goursat theorem and ignore the fact that $ f(z) $ is not analytic inside $C$. Right? Sorry for so many questions. I am trying to make sure I understand the concept very well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Josh Yes, you're right. We cannot use the CG theorem since we have *no* analytic function within the enclosed domain by the simple path. Just like with the integrals $\;\oint_\gamma z^ndz=0\;,\;\;n\neq-1\;$ ,  by direct parametrization and etc, for any closed path $\;\gamma\;$ enclosing zero. We don't use CG here.